# Installing Python oauth, setuptools issues

Tags: python, oauth, setuptools

I'm on Mac OS X Lion, and I have two Python versions on my machine (2.6 and 3.1). Unfortunately I *have* to have both 2 and 3 for different purposes (classes).

I'm trying to install the oauth2 module, and am receiving the following error

```
67-194-12-228:simplegeo-python-oauth2-1fcc1a6 xanderflood$ python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

All my research indicates that this problem occurs because oauth isn't currently compatible with Python 3. However, I've checked and double-checked that "python" starts my 2.6 terminal and "python3" starts my 3.1 terminal. I've installed many packages before to Python 2.6 in this way.

Any ideas on what's wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed the Python 2.6 yourself, you need to install a version of [`setuptools`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) or its newer fork [`Distribute`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) for that Python instance.  Each Python instance must have its own version.  The Apple-supplied system Pythons come with versions of `setuptools` already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Install Python 2.6 or above version:

```
pip install requests-oauth
```

[maraujop/requests-oauth](https://github.com/maraujop/requests-oauth)